# $p$ is an odd prime less than $m$ and $a\in \mathbb Z$ then $p|a^m-1$ implies $p|m$

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, examples-counterexamples, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $a\in \mathbb Z$ and $\mathit\Phi_m(x)$.

Now I know that if $p$ is an odd prime less than $m$ and $p$ divides $\mathit\Phi_m(a)$ then $p$ divides $m$.

As $\mathit\Phi_m(a)$ divides $x^m-1$ in $\mathbb Z [x]$ is a stronger version of the above statement true, that is

> **If $p$ is an odd prime less than $m$ and $p$ divides $a^m-1$ then $p$ divides $m$**

I couldn't find a valid argument to prove this nor was I able to find a counterexample.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, with your bolded stronger version of the statement, consider $p = 3$, $m = 4$ and $a = 2$. Then $a^m - 1 = 2^4 - 1 = 15$, so $p \mid a^m - 1$ but $p \not\mid m$.

Comment: Thanks . Actually I tried to prove the first statement by exploiting the fact $p|\mathit\Phi_m(a)$ implies $ p|a^m-1$ but now I see it was a wrong apporach .